# Push update in real time to a bower via process?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a script written in PHP and it run in the background on Linux.

Whatever happening in the script, it insert a log into a database.

I could use ajax to refresh every 3 seconds on the browser to pull update via database.

However, I prefer a real time push a browser, how can that be done?

Comment: `WebSockets`, the only reliable real time implementation via http.

Comment: check node.js and socket.io or html5 web sockets. Also have a look at comet and also long polling.